# Функция, работающая только 10 раз в минуту c#

Tags: c#, консоль

Функция вызывается, если в консоль пишешь `test`
Если много раз писать это слово, то будет флуд, надо чтобы функцию можно было вызывать 10 раз в минуту

Comment: так напишите. В чем проблема?

Comment: Перефразируйте свой вопрос, пожалуйста. После нескольких прочиток пришло понимание, что вы хотите добавить таймер? Или все же, о чем вы спрашиваете?

Comment: Таймер, именно.

Comment: Неконкретно. Покажите ваш код. И да, что должно случиться, если юзер печатает test три раза подряд: процедура должна выполниться сейчас, через 10 минут и через 20, или лишние вызовы должны быть отброшены?

Comment: Для примера:
Юзер пишет `test`, ему в ответ выдается `test1`
Если юзер пишет больше `test` больше 10 раз в минуту, то функция не должна вызываться(как-то так)

Comment: @user281592, Покажите ваш код)

Comment: очередь. если больше 9(10-1), то лишнее убрать. Добавить текущее время. Сравнить с 1 в очереди. Вызвать функцию или игнор.

Answer (score 2):

Запомните отметку времени, а при следующем вызове проверяйте ее:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch(); // Секундомер
sw.Start();
// Переменная для хранения метки времени
var prevStamp = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
while (true)
{
    var c = Console.ReadLine();
    if (c == "test")
    {
        // Если прошло менее 6 с (6000 мс) - пропускаем
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds - prevStamp < 6000) continue;
        // Иначе - выполняем метод
        Test();
        // И сохраняем новую отметку времени
        prevStamp = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: 10 раз в минуту не значит раз в 6 сек или реже. Можно 10 раз за первую секунду, а потом через 59 сек.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev, вполне возможно, что автор ещё сам не до конца понял что ему нужно. Пусть он попробует и отметит подходящий ответ галочкой :)

Answer (score 1):

Создайте переменную счётчик, которая будет увеличиваться каждый раз, когда пользователь вводит test. Если переменная больше или равна 10, тогда не вызывайте вашу функцию.
На C# особо не писал,  может можно лучше сделать, но смысл такой:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static int testCount = 0;
        public static void printTest1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test1");
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.Elapsed += (sender, arguments) => testCount = 0;
            myTimer.Interval = 60000;
            myTimer.Start();
            if (Console.ReadLine() == "test")
                testCount++;
            if (testCount < 10)
                printTest1();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не счетчик, а время последнего выполнения функции. Или более сложно - количество выполнений за последнюю минуту.

Comment: @Igor Ну, если придерживаться моего решения, то можно в таймере каждую минуту сбрасывать счётчик, довольно простой и рабочий вариант